# In R, if you use the command `options(digits = 3)`, will it artificially round your computation?

Tags: r

In R, I sometimes set parameters like `options(digits = 3)` or `options(scipen = 5)` for viewing purposes. However, today I realized that doing this may artificially round my computation. For example, if I use `options(digits = 1)`, and compute `1/3`, would it round to 0 before going on to the next computation? Thanks.

Comment: `?options` - *"digits: controls the number of digits to print when printing numeric values."* By the sounds of that, it is only for `print`ing, nothing else. The underlying value should not be affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran the following scenario, and think it answers the confusion:

```
x <- 1/3
options(digits = 1)
x
[1] 0.3

options(digits = 2)
x
[1] 0.33

options(digits = 6)
x
[1] 0.333333
```

Also, if you're using Rstudio, you can check the `Environment` pane and you'll see that the actual value is not changed.

Comment: That doesn't definitively show much. OP already knows changing the option affects how it is displayed. If you showed that `options(digits=0); x <- 1/3; x * 3` gave `1` instead of `0` you'd prove a point though.

Comment: Fair enough. TBH, I am personally happy with looking at the environment pane, just didn't wan't to paste a screenshot here. Removed the objectionable word anyway :)